# Web service to send SMSs to Italy

Tags: web-services, api, sms, sms-gateway

I need to send 100-1000 SMSs per month. At the beginning i just need to send messages to Italy, but i don't want to exclude other possibilities. Which web service do you use? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [GlobalItalia](http://www.globalitalia.it/sms/) service.
It works very well...

Comment: why? did you try something else?

Comment: @vad: no, I surfed the web searching for what I needed and, after studying some other option, I choose GlobalItalia. Even if it's not perfect, I appreciate it and it works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/).

Comment: why? did you try something else?